# SQL Server Partial commit in transaction

Tags: sql-server, sqltransaction

I have a transaction and two tables where i am inserting some data, can I do partial commits in SQL server

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION tran1
  BEGIN  TRY
    --Insert into Table1
    --Insert into Table2
COMMIT TRANSACTION  tran1                           
  END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tran1 
END CATCH
```

Above code will rollback both tables data, is there a way we can commit table 1 if there is no error on table 1 insert but rollback table 2 if there is any error occurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, although transactions are indeed atomic you could use a [savepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/save-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). So in your case, the code could look like this (untested):

```
BEGIN  TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    --Insert into Table1

    -- savepoint
    SAVE TRANSACTION tran1

    --Insert into Table2

    -- commit the whole transaction
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    -- rollback to savepoint
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION tran1 
END CATCH
```

You may have to adjust insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't.
A transaction is atomic. That is all of the steps are performed as one, commited together, or rolled back.
If you put both inserts into a single transaction, you can't commit to one table.
You can use different transactions if possible.

Comment: can you look at above answer, do you see any issue with above approach

Comment: Looks okay actually. That savepoint is a MSSQL feature. In this case its almost the same as having 2 transactions, except that the first fails the 2 nd will not work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: No i am just exploring if this feature exists in MSSQL or not nothing more, thanks anyway for helping me out

Comment: NP, one other method I can think if is to put try catch inside the transaction. That way it will try the both tabels

Comment: But again this is not something you want to do in the transaction, because of what transactions are intended for

Comment: sure I won't be using it unless requirement arises as such thank you