# How many transactions were started during the execution of the request?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqltransaction

I have a transaction. The code is

```
set implicit_transactions on
select getdate()
begin transaction
begin transaction
   select * from price p1, product p2 where p1.product_id = p2.product_id
rollback
   delete from PRODUCT where product_id = 100871
   select 100860,2,3,getdate(),null from PRODUCT
commit
drop table price
```

The question is how many transactions were started during the execution of the request? As I understand it, some people refer to this as a "nested transaction" although this is not official terminology.

So, from the server's point of view, were there 2 transactions started, or 1?

Comment: You can find out using a `SELECT @@trancount` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Sql-server has no nested transactions. If you want to save part of the work use `SAVE TRANSACTION` See for example  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63924746/sql-server-partial-commit-in-transaction

Comment: @Squirrel Yes, but it's not always immediately obvious which commands open a transaction in implicit mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The answer is neither of those.

**It is three: one rolled back, one committed, the last one hanging.**

> ***EDIT:* Original version was wrong about `select getdate`**
>
> [Quote from the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) SELECT statements that do not select from a table do not start implicit transactions. For example `SELECT GETDATE();` or `SELECT 1, 'ABC';` do not require transactions.

---

As follows:

- You switch on `implicit_transactions`, this means commands open **and leave open** a transaction, they do not auto-commit.
- `select getdate()` does **not** open a transaction, as no table is referenced
- `begin transaction` opens a transaction
- `begin transaction` increments `@@trancount` to 2
- `select * from` makes no change, would normally open a transaction
- `rollback` rolls **everything** back
- `delete from` opens, but does not commit, a transaction.
- `select 100860` does nothing
- `commit` commits
- `drop table price` opens and leaves hanging a transaction

**What happens if `implicit_transactions` is off?** The answer is **also three transactions**, all committed except for the explicit one which is rolled back

- `select getdate()` does nothing.
- `begin transaction` opens, but does not commit, a transaction.
- `begin transaction` increments `@@trancount` to 2
- `select * from` makes no change
- `rollback` rolls **everything** back
- `delete from` opens, and commits, a transaction.
- `select 100860` does nothing.
- `commit` commits nothing
- `drop table price` opens, and commits, a transaction.

**Please note:** `rollback transaction` without a semi-colon `;` is dangerous, as the next word can be interpreted as a transaction name. An incorrect transaction name means nothing happens. This is why you should **always** terminate statements with a semi-colon.